# ¿Cuál sería un buen sinónimo de «nerfear»?

Tags: sinónimos, vulgaridades

«Nerfeado», en la cultura popular actual y, principalmente en el mundo de los videojuegos, se refiere a un elemento o personaje que ha disminuido sus posibilidades dentro del juego, es decir, se encuentra limitado. Se dice que un personaje de videojuego está «nerfeado»  cuando los desarrolladores lo ajustan para disminuir sus habilidades y poderes con el objetivo de balancear la experiencia del juego. También se aplica así al cine o a la literatura, coloquialmente hablando.

Sin embargo, si quiero referirme a esta definición sin usar este vulgarismo, ¿ qué sinónimo podría utilizar?

La definición más cercana para sustituir «nerfear» podría ser «debilitar» (`1. tr. Disminuir la fuerza, el vigor o el poder de alguien o algo.`), aunque quizá pueda dar a entender que el «debilitado» ha disminuido su fuerza o poder durante la trama, y no antes de ella, como se da a entender con el objeto en cuestión.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dado que el término «Nerfeado»,  «Nerfear»  está inspirado en la marca "Nerf", que se dedica a fabricar "**juguetes blandos**" y que no causan perjuicio o daño, un sinónimo ajustado podría ser, "**suavizar o templar**", referidos a los **poderes o habilidades** de aquellos objetos o personajes que mencionas.

También podría servir "**blandear**", "**blandeado**", más acorde incluso con el nombre que inspiro el término "Nerf", "blando".

**blandear**

De blando y -ear.

1. intr. Aflojar, ceder.

https://dle.rae.es/blandear

Comment: !Ah que bien! Una respuesta corta. :)

Comment: @lambie ¿ Qué tal?.  ¿Qué haría yo, sin todos sus enriquecedores consejos colmados de sabias palabras en cualquier ámbito de la vida? ;)